# IMO WSTP does not work with the Visual Studio 2019 tools, can you prove otherwise?

Tags: documentation, mathlink-or-wstp, external-calls

Can LINK addtwo.obj addtwotm.obj wstp64i4.lib /OUT:addtwo.exe actually work with Visual Studio 2019 tools, if so how?

```
My setup is as I reported in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/232846/where-to-place-the-essential-wstp-files-in-visual-studio-2019/232955#232955
```

I am out of my depth here:

```
LINK addtwo.obj addtwotm.obj wstp64i4.lib /OUT:addtwo.exe

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.25.28614.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

addtwotm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage referenced in function WSDefaultYielder
addtwotm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageA referenced in function WSDefaultYielder

( Several more ... )

addtwo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
```

**If LINK addtwo.obj addtwotm.obj wstp64i4.lib /OUT:addtwo.exe works with the Visual Studio 2019 tools please show me the proof, so that I can keep working on this.**

I am currently at the decision point of installing Visual Studio 2012(!) because at least the documentation seems to be up-to-date with that version.

Note that I am working on starting up an open source project adding full Pari/GP functionality to Mathematica. Should this be done with VS 2012 tools?? Or: should I use MathLink?

Perhaps Wolfram is a 100% Mac shop, ignoring the majority of computer users.

Comment: The several more are really important. But that link line should include kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib.

Comment: Have done that before. Does it work on your system? If so, what is your config?

Answer (score 2):

My "solution" is, finally, the following. Do not waste your time trying to get Mathematica WSTP working with Visual Studio 2019. It does not work. ( Sadly, nobody proved otherwise. )

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 11 2012(!) which lines up with the documentation provided with Mathemathica 12.1, and, as expected, I was able to produce addtwo.exe.

Comment: I could connect VS 2019 to mathematica kernel and works fine, what is your problem?

Comment: Lucky you. If only you said that last October. :-) - Since then I dumped VS, used a simple, open source, c IDE, called geany and finished the work I had to do in C. Thanks for your reply.