# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSInitialize

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I tried to run very simple example of connecting to WSTP. I checked a few links in this site but none of them could resolved my issue. I added three .lib files to visual studio location from this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/232846/where-to-place-the-essential-wstp-files-in-visual-studio-2019) and also linked to my program on visual studio. Also i did it for wstp.h and .exe. each one as explained in documentation
[developer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Windows.html#13917). I modified the linker on C++ project and added all these files to current project on visual studio. But still i am getting this problem. I wish they had better documentation. Can someone help me , thanks
**error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSInitialize

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSDeinitialize

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSOpenString

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSClose**

```
#include "wstp.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    WSENV env;
    WSLINK link;
    int error;

    env = WSInitialize((WSEnvironmentParameter)0);
    if (env == (WSENV)0)
    { /* unable to initialize WSTP environment */
    }

    link = WSOpenString(env, "/usr/local/bin/math -mathlink", &error);
    if (link == (WSLINK)0 || error != WSEOK)
    { /* unable to create link to the Kernel */
    }

    /* ... */

    WSClose(link);
    WSDeinitialize(env);

    return 0;
}
```

***EDITED Solved: beside the right answer, i should have compile as x64 because my system is 64bit, but i ran the program as x86 and got those errors***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those particular linker errors mean that the input library was not added under the linker settings.  I put together [an example project](https://github.com/ihojnicki/WSTPVSExample) on GitHub that you can use for reference.  The paths are currently setup for the default installation location for Mathematica 12.2.

Comment: that really helped me, one more mistake which i did, I compiled the code as x86 but my system is 64 bits, so i had to change it to x64. thanks

Comment: could you tell me what should be instead of -mathlink? is that mathlink.exe? thanks

Comment: In newer versions, `-wstp` is preferred.  But `-mathlink` still exists for compatibility reasons.